# Flutter Getx listener is not getting triggered when the value is same

Tags: flutter, stream, flutter-getx

I need a way to notify whenever an observable is set to value, regardless it's the same as the pervious one or not.

I've used `listen()`, `addListener()` and `ever` and none of them get called with setting same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to call `refresh()` on it every time you make an assignment. Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen()));
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({super.key});

  final RxInt test = 2.obs;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Obx(() {
          print('triggered');
          return TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                test.value = 1;
                test.refresh(); //leaving this out won't trigger rebuilds anymore
              },
              child: Text(test.toString()));
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that this maybe will cause an unnecessary extra trigger when the value does in fact change. You might want to check if it is in fact the same before calling `refresh()`